# Google Cloud Build Generating cloud_run_revision warnings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a system built by Google Cloud Build and running in Google Cloud Run. It detects when I've pushed new code into Bitbucket and automatically builds from there.

The last change I made to code was a few days ago. Today I noticed a number of messages in the logs explorer containing the following kind of info...

```
  {
  "insertId": "62eec4ec00054bed93ba2600",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestUrl": "https://gx-txxx-ylb2wvn3ma-uc.a.run.app/internal/jolokia/",
    "requestSize": "776",
    "status": 404,
    "responseSize": "858",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36",
    "remoteIp": "216.131.109.149",
    "serverIp": "216.239.32.53",
    "latency": "0.006097606s",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "gr-test",
      "configuration_name": "gx-txxx",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "central-segment-190xxx",
      "revision_name": "gx-txxx-00086-nis"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-08-06T19:45:48.347117Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "00c527f6d4848dafa449ff8b561a21d622e3e35600254dea2fa54a4e9c1fddd150910889f9a9e0c94769abb5b9e29520fc3b0822a31d84b121acbd5bbd0d65b186",
    "managed-by": "gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run",
    "commit-sha": "33745757dcc97bdfa08d37ba1e4b238607634fe2",
    "gcb-trigger-id": "8511bbc7-62c8-4f52-bf85-cfd9cd026d9f",
    "gcb-build-id": "3290e3e0-7b22-4034-9d96-5af1d0c3cf6c"
  },
  "logName": "projects/central-segment-190216/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "trace": "projects/central-segment-190216/traces/45562a3a3ea82892a4453ad4edc98a89",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-08-06T19:45:48.390028733Z",
  "spanId": "14733853662024484454"
}
```

I haven't made any changes to my code in the past few days and Cloud Build doesn't point to any new builds since the last one I did. So, what could be causing these warnings? Is this a security issue about which I should be concerned?

Thank you!

<<Mod1 - I've posted the complete JSON message>>

Comment: Is there a text or JSON payload in the log entries associated with the warning? That should include more details of the issue. Security issues are unlikely to be posted as warnings (although it's possible). Warnings indicate something of concern which isn't breaking your code.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for responding. I've put the complete JSON message into my request.

Comment: Thanks! The log entry corresponds to a `GET` against `https://gx-txxx-ylb2wvn3ma-uc.a.run.app/internal/jolokia/` which is not found.

Comment: Thank you, @DazWilkin ! I don't call that URL from within my code so I'm assuming that it's coming from somewhere else (perhaps the remote IP noted in the JSON?). Is this something to worry about or something that just happens when your app is exposed to the web?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You'll see various well-known paths probed. I'm unsure why it's correlated with the `WARNING` in the log though. Not found is an error. It may be a way to minimize alerts  when, like this, you've no control over the paths that will be scanned.

Comment: Thank you! If you want to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the chosen answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log entry shown corresponds to a `GET` against `https://gx-txxx-ylb2wvn3ma-uc.a.run.app/internal/jolokia/` which is not found.

In this case, with a publicly available service (and as OP points out) corroborating the request against the unfamiliar logged remote IP, the request is indicative of probing by "others".

Such requests are not always malicious in intent but, in this case, it's likely a bot searching for some weakness. In this case, I suspect, looking for a site that supports [`jolokia` protocol](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html).

It's prudent to pay attention to these requests and they will increase your costs. They may do so intentionally e.g. [denial of service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). Google provides [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) to help protect sites. There are many so-called [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) tools available.

It's curious that Google is reporting [`404`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) as `warning` but this may be a way to avoid flooding logs with errors in cases like this which are unfortunate but expected.